# Cinema Queue Doesn't Work Java

Tags: java, arrays, queue

I need to be able to verify an age in the main class so for example if the name and age is added to the queue and when the person tries to leave if the age is less than 18 then a message appears saying "left because too young" or if the person is over 18 then a message appears saying "person left"

This is my main Class

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Queue q = new Queue();


    Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Join (j), leave (l) or end (e)? ");
    String action = k.nextLine();
    while (!action.equalsIgnoreCase("e"))
    {
         if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("j"))
        {
            System.out.print("Enter Name ");
             String Name = k.nextLine();
             System.out.print("Enter Age : ");
             int Age = k.nextInt();
            Person p1 = new Person(Name,Age);
            q.add(p1);

            System.out.println(Name + " Age " + Age + " Joined");   
        } 

        else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("l"))
        {
            if (!q.isEmpty())
            {
                System.out.println(q.remove() + " Person Left");
            } 
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Queue Empty");
            }
        } 
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid operation");
        }
        System.out.print("Join (j), leave (l) or end (e)? ");
        action = k.nextLine();
```

I also have a person class with the name and age and also a Queue Class.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just add an if statement?

```
int Age = k.nextInt();
Person p1 = new Person(Name, Age);
q.add(p1);
if (Age < 18) {
   q.remove(p1);
   System.out.println("left because too young");
}
```